# Sitecore User Group Belarus Meetup - July 26

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

We are glad to announce the next meetup of the Sitecore User Group Belarus that will occur July 26th at 19:00 (UTC 15:00) in "Imaguru" (Fabriciusa 4, Minsk).

https://www.meetup.com/Sitecore-User-Group-Belarus/events/252114873/

This time we’ll celebrate our anniversary as it will be our 10th meetup. Throughout two years of our user group we’ve managed to unite and grow the Sitecore community in Belarus, bring interesting speakers from all over the world and see speakers growing among local experts.

10th meetup is noticeable for 3 great guests:

Peter Nazarov (https://twitter.com/pnz_peter) - Sitecore Development and Delivery Consultant, UK.

Peter will speak about ‘**Sitecore Development Phase Quick Start – Simple Spec Path**’

Simple Spec Path presentation makes a proposal for a software development and delivery approach that enables a rapid start of Sitecore project implementation phase in a short period of time. The approach allows executing a transition from the high-level business requirements to a certain level of implementation details which are essential for enterprise-level software development start and successful delivery of the final software product.

Serhii Shushliapin (https://twitter.com/shushlyapin) - Senior Software Developer at ‎Implicit ApS, author of Sitecore.FakeDb unit testing framework, Sitecore MVP, Ukraine.

**Sitecore unit testing gotchas**.

"Have you ever tried to do unit testing in Sitecore? Was it smooth enough or would you rather say it's too complicated and it is not worth the time spent? Have you dug deep to understand if that is a technical reason or anything else preventing you/your team from getting benefits of unit testing or Test Driven Development?
I’ve been doing TDD since ~2011 and I have seen numerous teams succeeding and failing in that. In my talk I’ll go through the list of common mistakes and share my observations that will help you to become more confident in this area."

Andrey Polyakov (https://twitter.com/APaliakou) - Senior Sitecore Developer from Brimit, Sitecore Commerce MVP.

Andrey will talk about "**Sitecore Experience Commerce 9 - expectations and reality**".

He’ll show what's new in the Sitecore commerce 9.0 and how the new functionality eases development process or helps to reduce your time-to-market.

Comment: Community Bulletin promotion began 2 days ago